# Redundant pages on printout

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-8

I need to print a div, for this I'm hiding everything else, but on IE8 (on IE11 too) my div is printed on 22pages! (or less depending on the page behind). I'm making all other stuff invisible and reducing the height of the body but it doesnt help.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="loading">more divs/p's/whatnots</div>
            <div class="navigation">more divs/p's/whatnots</div>
            <div class="page">more divs/p's/whatnots</div>
            <div class="nav-buttons">more divs/p's/whatnots</div>
            <div class="certificate">more divs/p's/whatnots</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my media=print style

```
body {
    height: 100px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.certificate * {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I can't do `display:none;` in the `body *` as this includes the certificate div (and it's content) so there is no easy way to restore it in `.certificate *`.

What else I could do to print it without a hassle on IE?

**EDIT** so far the only working solution is to use `display:none;` but so I don't have to restore it I'm applying this not to `body *` but to more specific paths e.g. `body .page *`, `body #wrapper *` but in a way so I don't "hide" certificate (thus don't have to restore it). If there is a better more flexible way to do it, I'm all ears.

**EDIT2** also I could do `body #wrapper > *` to hide all children of `#wrapper` but not going any further, then just `body #wrapper .certificate` to restore `display` property works

```
body #wrapper > * 
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

body #wrapper .certificate {
    visibility: visible;
    display: table;
}
```